# Vue.js with $this.refs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <p ref="uploadCvText" @click="openUploadFileDialogueCV(this.$refs.input_file_cv)">+ Upload Your CV (*)</p>
      <input ref="input_file_cv" type="file" value="" name="input_file_cv" @change="handleCvUpload()">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    openUploadFileDialogueCV(e) {
      e.click();
    }
  }
</script>
```

> the problem is that (ref) is not allowed to be used in template ! so how can i 
>   refer to html element and let openUploadFileDialogueCV() function 
>   works correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `this` in template, use `@click="openUploadFileDialogueCV($refs.input_file_cv)` instead